# docker-compose and term2 on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, iterm2

I am on Mac, El-Capitan 10.11.5

Until Today,  I was able to run the docker-daemon by calling "docker quickstart terminal"

then going into my project folder and doing a docker-compose up

Now, when I run that, I keep getting

```
    docker-compose --verbose up --timeout 120


compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.auth.parse_auth: Found entry (registry=u'https://index.docker.io/v1/', username=u'my_user')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 58, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 106, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 34, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 79, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 55, in get_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 76, in version
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
  File "site-packages/docker/client.py", line 120, in _get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Is there a quick solution for this problem? my versions are

docker-machine version 0.7.0, build a650a40

Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe

docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35

iterm2 Build 3.0.0

virtual Machine
Version 5.0.20 r106931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved this problem by adding the following line into my `.profile` file

```
alias docker_compose_run='eval "$(docker-machine env default)" && docker-compose up'
```

then I simply run `docker_compose_run`